# ColdFusion Multiple Domain Redirect

Tags: iis, coldfusion, http-status-code-301, coldfusion-8, cflocation

I have many domains (www.vf1.com, www.vf2.com, www.vf3.com etc) which all point to my main domain (www.vf.com). How do I do a 301 redirect from these other domains to my main domain?

So if someone hits www.vf1.com/news/1234 they should get redirected to www.vf.com/news/1234

I also have domains such as images.vf.com, css.vf.com and js.vf.com that I don't need redirecting

I'm using ColdFusion 8 on IIS (but I don't have access to IIS at the moment)

I tried the below on a URL such as http://www.festivalreviews.co.uk/latest/news/14500 but it gets redirected to http://www.virtualfestivals.com/index.cfm

```
<cfif cgi.http_host IS 'www.festivalreviews.co.uk'>
    <cfset jjURL = 'http://www.virtualfestivals.com' & CGI.PATH_INFO>
    <cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved Permanently">
    <cfheader name="Location" value="#jjURL#">
</cfif>
```

Thanks

Comment: I would be inclined to handle HTTP stuff like redirects on the HTTP server, not via CF.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Adam, if possible, this would probably be better handled using your web server. Having said that, I have had to do similar things in the past with ColdFusion. When I need to rebuild URLs I typically use different CGI variables than what you tried. See if this works for you.

```
<cfif CGI.SERVER_NAME IS 'www.festivalreviews.co.uk'>
    <cfset jjURL = 'http://www.virtualfestivals.com' & CGI.SCRIPT_NAME>
    <cfif CGI.QUERY_STRING NEQ ''>
        <cfset jjURL = jjURL & '?' & CGI.QUERY_STRING>
    </cfif>
    <cfheader statuscode="301" statustext="Moved Permanently">
    <cfheader name="Location" value="#jjURL#">
</cfif>
```

`CGI.SERVER_NAME` - Server's hostname, DNS alias, or IP address
`CGI.SCRIPT_NAME` - Virtual path to the script that is executing
`CGI.QUERY_STRING` - Query information that follows the ? in the URL that referenced this script

You can read more about the CGI variables in the [documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Expressions_8.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since ColdFusion 8, I use <cflocation> (because CF8 added the statusCode attribute) for these kinds of redirects.

```
<cfif CGI.SERVER_NAME EQ 'www.festivalreviews.co.uk'>
    <cfset jjURL = 'http://www.virtualfestivals.com' & CGI.SCRIPT_NAME>
    <cfif CGI.QUERY_STRING NEQ ''>
        <cfset jjURL = jjURL & '?' & CGI.QUERY_STRING>
    </cfif>
    <cflocation url="#jjURL#" addtoken="no" statuscode="301">
</cfif>
```

<cflocation> documentation: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cflocation